# Moving AVP to Video SE - Next Steps

Tags: discussion, status-completed

We're pleased to announce that the Video / Audio split is nearly complete, at least as far as the disruptive phases of such endeavors tend to go. Sound is now, for the most part, moved over to Sound Design SE.

What we've got to do next is get Video all taken care of, and here's the plan:

1. Break the current video.stackexchange.com redirect
2. Re-name AVP into Video Production, with the URL of video.stackexchange.com
3. Make avp.stackexchange.com into a redirect to video.stackexchange.com
4. Update help center articles, text prompts that the site says
5. Clean up tags / squash any strings that need updating as needed

This process is slated to happen on Friday, February 7. It'll probably involve a few hours of things working strangely, the site being in maintenance mode, and other quirks. We'll get these sorted out rather quickly, and with any luck most folks won't notice anything but the URL and description changing.

This means, you don't have to do anything but wait - there's no need to create accounts elsewhere or worry about badges / anything else going away.

After that, we're going to open up a conversation about who the new Video SE moderators should be, and a discussion on opportunities for us to do some surgical promotion to help bring traffic back up after such a disruptive move.

All in all, this should go quite smoothly.

Stay tuned, as I'll be frequenting meta this week with additional announcements, and more transition related guidance. Hang tight, we're almost done!

In the mean time, I'm looking for some input from you folks on what the new site description should be. Right now, we've got this:

> The Audio-Video Production Stack Exchange is for engineers, producers, editors, and enthusiasts spanning the fields of audio, video, and media creation.

This will naturally become:

> The Video Production Stack Exchange is for engineers, producers, editors and enthusiasts in the fields of video and media creation.

That's basically removing the audio part. Should something else change?

---

This has now been completed, and descriptions / text shown in various places has been updated. The new site url is video.stackexchange.com, and AVP will continue to redirect here so that migration histories on Sound Design point back to the proper origin.

Please report any quirks with text / links in answers here, though it's important to note that all kinds of things will be quirky for the next few hours while the redirect changes clear caches, and cached content on Area 51 / stackexchange.com / etc.

See? I told you it wouldn't hurt ... much :) Thanks to the awesome Geoff Dalgas for pulling these levers so smoothly.

Comment: I think that's all that is needed.

Comment: Help Center still needs updating for the [on-topic](http://video.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page.  The biggest trick will be balancing how we describe what audio (as it relates to video) questions are on topic and where that line is.

Comment: @AJHenderson Whoops, I forgot to take a pass through that. Took a stab at it, by no means permanent or carved in stone, but at least it looks like it belongs on _this_ site now :) (I hope to have 3 new mods in place here next week that can pick up tweaking things in the help center).

Comment: For audio questions that didn't get picked up in the bulk move, do we flag then individually, or post on Meta? [example](http://video.stackexchange.com/q/1309/741)

Comment: *[Sound Design](https://sound.stackexchange.com/tour)*. The old [was *audio.stackexchange.com*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87052/where-can-i-ask-questions-about-headphone-repair#comment1277408_87052).